# System.Web.HttpParseException: 'The code block is missing a closing "}" character

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am facing some issue with razor syntax to pass list of string with partial view. Here is my code :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @{ IList<string> model = new List<string> {"nb-NO", "nn-NO", "sv-SE", "da-DK", "en-GB", "se-NO", "fi-FI", "de-DE"}; }
        <li>@Html.Partial("_AppLanguage", model)</li>
</ul>
```

when i execute, it shows me this error:

[image]

Can anybody tell me whats the wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I got my solution. The issue is not in my razor syntax. The issue was in my `_AppLanguage` partial view. There i made a mistake to grub the model. I used `@{var model = @Model;}` instead of `@{var model = Model;}`